# Combinatorics - Optimisation (Minimum number of questions)

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, integer-programming

An exam centre is going to prepare question papers for 160 students where each paper has 9 questions from 9 different topics (one question per topic). They can allow upto 2 collisions, i.e. at most 2 out of the 9 questions can be the same for any two of the papers. What is the minimum number of questions that should be prepared for each topic?

My work follows:

First I tried to find out what is total number of total questions that needs to be prepared. I was thinking of using Inclusion-Exclusion principle but then it's too big to calculate the cardinality of the union of 160 sets.

Then I started to work on small number of sets starting from 2, 3, 4, ... and progressing in the hope of finding any pattern or logic. Finally it would be like a 160 x 9 matrix where no two rows have more than 2 elements in common.
I prepared the first few rows as shown below:

A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1 I1

A1 B2 C2 D2 E1 F2 G2 H2 I2

A2 B1 C2 D3 E2 F1 G2 H3 I3

A3 B3 C1 D2 E2 F3 G1 H2 I3

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I

I am getting stuck at the 5th row and not able to bring 2 elements common from first 4 rows. Not able to determine if it is logically bound to happen or is there something wrong in my initial technique of optimisation.

1 Paper: Minimum number of total questions = 9

2 Papers: Minimum number of total questions = 9 + 7 = 16

3 Papers: Minimum number of total questions = 9 + 7 + 5 = 21

4 Papers: Minimum number of total questions = 9 + 7 + 5 + 3 = 24

5 Papers: Minimum no. of total questions = 9 + 7 + 5 + ? = ?

Next another thought came to my mind.

I've been thinking about the simpler case where there is at most one collision. (That is, questions may be re-used, but not in a way that two exam papers contain the same two questions.)

Suppose we only need two questions (denoted by A and B topic questions) instead of 9. With just two questions, the "one-collision" requirement is the same as saying all the papers are unique.) Then we can show that 26 questions suffices to generate 160 papers. Here's how:

First, we show there have to be at least 26 questions. This comes from the pigeonhole principle. Let k be the number of A questions. Then there is some A question that occurs at least 160/k times, and so we
need at least 160/k B questions to go with this one, for a total of k + 160/k (rounded up to the next integer) questions. The minimum value of this expression is 26, which occurs for all k in the range 10 <= k <= 16.

But I am not able to generate an idea on how to proceed to solve the given problem. How to Mathematically model the problem statement? What I am not very sure about is whether we try to find out the smallest number of total questions required, say Q, for a subset of N papers and then our answer shall be Q*(floor(160/N)) + Q', where Q' is smallest number of total questions required for the remaining 160 - N*(floor (160/N)) papers.

Please, help me as I am missing the required optimisation strategy to be used.

High Regards,

Shamik Banerjee

Comment: Is it assumed that an equal number of questions will be prepared for each of the nine topics?  The phrasing of the Question suggests that there is such a constant, but note that if two questions are allowed to be the same for all students (on two different topics), we would only need one question for two of the topics and 160 questions for the remaining seven topics.

Comment: Each question paper has a total of 9 questions and there is 1 question for each of the 9 topics i.e. a one-to-one matching between the topics and questions in each and every of the 160 question papers. At the most not more than 2 questions can be common between any two papers. The main objective is to minimise the total number of distinct questions and then just a break up of how many questions are to be prepared from the 9 topics. The number of distinct questions per topic may or may not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

(Not a complete solution)

**Showing that we need at least 5 question in each topic.**

Let there be $Q$ questions in each topic.
Set up the standard incidence matrix of 160 rows as students and $9Q$ columns as questions.
Each row has 9 1's in it, for a total of $160 \times 9 =1440$ 1's.
Let $c_i$ be the number of 1's in each column. We have $ \sum c_i = 1440.$

We bound the number of column pairs of 1's:
Every 2 rows share at most 2 column pairs, so there are $\leq 2\times{160 \choose 2} = 25440 $ column pairs.
The number of columns pairs is $ \sum { c_i \choose 2 } \geq 9Q \times {\frac{1440}{9Q} \choose 2 }  $.
Solving $25440 \geq 9Q \times {\frac{1440}{9Q} \choose 2 } $ gives us $ Q \geq \frac{480}{109}$ so $ Q \geq 5$.

---

**Trying to show $Q = 5$ works.**

---

**Showing that $Q = 13$ is more than sufficient.**

Consider the $13^2=169$ pairs of integers $(i, j)$ with $1 \leq i, j \leq 13 $.
Student $S_{(i,j)} $ for topic $T $ will get question $i+tj \pmod{13}$.
Then Student $S_{(i_1, j_1)}$ and $S_{(i_2, j_2)}$ will share a common question if $ i_1 - i_2 = t (j_1 - j_2) \pmod{13}$, which has a unique solution $t$, so they will share at most 1 question in common.

---

**$Q = 9 $ is sufficient**

Claim from Rob Pratt in the comments.

Comment: I had the same mod-13 idea! It's interesting that this strategy actually supports ~26 topics (by using the same $t$ for two topics), yet it doesn't immediately give us a solution with smaller $Q$ for only 9 topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extended help. Let me work on the construction for Q=9 as per your guidelines.

Comment: E.g. Taking Q = 5, we get (9Q)×C((1440)/(9Q), 2) = 45*C(32, 2) = 22320 < 25440. Please, help me to figure out how to achieve the solution from this point.

Comment: 1) I believe you have a typo in your inequality, you went from 106/9 to 109/3 for no clear reason to me. 2) Given that the bound is somewhat loose ($60/7 = 8.6$), I suspect a manual approach is possible, but haven't spent a lot of time thinking about it. Check out coding theory (Hamming distance, etc) for ideas on how to do the construction.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo i.e. 106/3 was wrongly typed as 106/9 in the first place. So, Q >= 5 is a correct calculation. I have deleted my previous comment as I couldn't edit that but added the correction in the end.     Taking this into account do you suggest me check out coding theory (Hamming distance, etc) starting from a 160×45 standard incidence matrix. Please confirm once again as I apologise for that typo. The correct inequality follows:  (1440/(9Q)) - 1 <= (2*25440)/1440 = 106/3 ==> 1440/(9Q) <= 109/3 ==> Q >= 480/109 ==> Q >= 5 ==> 9Q >= 45.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong. Updated the writeup. With Q=5, I'm not certain of how to approach it. Def look into some coding theory for ideas.

Comment: Please, update the heading of your writeup which says, "Showing that we need at least 9 question in each topic." It should be "Showing that we need at least 5 question in each topic." Thanks a lot for your help and support.

Comment: $Q=9$ suffices.  Not sure yet whether it is the minimum.

Comment: 5 is insufficient because $5\times5\times5<160$, so by the pigeonhole principle, two exams would share the same 3-tuple of questions on the first three topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extended help & support.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an integer linear programming formulation.  Let binary decision variable $x_{s,t,q}$ indicate whether student $s$, topic $t$, is assigned question $q$.  Let $y_{s_1,s_2,t}$ indicate whether students $s_1$ and $s_2$ are assigned the same question for topic $t$.  Let $z_{t,q}$ indicate whether any student is assigned topic $t$, question $q$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{t,q} z_{t,q}$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_q x_{s,t,q} &= 1 &&\text{for all $s$ and $t$} \tag1\\
x_{s,t,q} &\le z_{t,q} &&\text{for all $s$, $t$, and $q$} \tag2\\
x_{s_1,t,q} + x_{s_2,t,q} - 1 &\le y_{s_1,s_2,t} &&\text{for all $s_1<s_2$, $t$, and $q$} \tag3\\
\sum_t y_{s_1,s_2,t} &\le 2 &&\text{for all $s_1<s_2$} \tag4
\end{align}

Constraint $(1)$ assigns exactly one question for each student and topic.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $x_{s,t,q} = 1 \implies z_{t,q} = 1$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $(x_{s_1,t,q} = 1 \land x_{s_2,t,q} = 1) \implies y_{s_1,s_2,t} = 1$.
Constraint $(4)$ prevents every pair of students from being assigned the same question for more than two topics.

For 160 students and 9 topics, here's a (not necessarily optimal) solution that uses only 9 questions per topic:
\begin{matrix}
8 &3 &7 &9 &5 &6 &8 &3 &9 \\
1 &2 &1 &6 &5 &6 &6 &2 &2 \\
1 &5 &4 &1 &7 &6 &3 &9 &8 \\
2 &6 &3 &1 &1 &5 &6 &9 &5 \\
8 &8 &9 &9 &7 &3 &3 &1 &3 \\
6 &1 &6 &4 &7 &2 &3 &3 &1 \\
4 &1 &2 &1 &1 &7 &3 &2 &7 \\
8 &2 &3 &6 &4 &7 &7 &4 &5 \\
8 &9 &9 &2 &6 &8 &4 &9 &7 \\
2 &6 &2 &2 &4 &9 &1 &4 &4 \\
6 &2 &2 &8 &2 &4 &6 &6 &1 \\
1 &4 &6 &3 &6 &9 &3 &5 &2 \\
9 &3 &1 &4 &6 &4 &1 &5 &4 \\
5 &9 &1 &4 &8 &6 &3 &6 &3 \\
6 &1 &4 &5 &6 &9 &2 &4 &8 \\
9 &8 &4 &2 &9 &2 &9 &5 &8 \\
8 &1 &2 &2 &2 &1 &9 &3 &2 \\
5 &3 &1 &2 &1 &9 &6 &3 &6 \\
8 &2 &7 &4 &2 &2 &4 &2 &6 \\
5 &4 &9 &2 &8 &7 &5 &5 &9 \\
9 &1 &3 &2 &8 &6 &7 &2 &6 \\
3 &7 &7 &5 &9 &7 &8 &5 &2 \\
6 &7 &8 &2 &1 &1 &4 &7 &1 \\
3 &7 &2 &1 &5 &9 &2 &9 &1 \\
4 &1 &8 &3 &2 &3 &2 &5 &4 \\
2 &4 &1 &8 &2 &1 &3 &7 &6 \\
2 &8 &2 &6 &9 &8 &2 &7 &7 \\
8 &9 &8 &8 &1 &6 &5 &1 &6 \\
9 &3 &8 &3 &3 &8 &3 &1 &1 \\
1 &3 &5 &2 &2 &6 &5 &7 &5 \\
3 &9 &5 &7 &9 &2 &6 &7 &1 \\
1 &5 &9 &9 &9 &1 &4 &4 &2 \\
4 &9 &9 &1 &8 &2 &8 &8 &6 \\
6 &8 &1 &3 &6 &7 &5 &1 &7 \\
7 &7 &9 &3 &9 &2 &3 &9 &5 \\
1 &2 &2 &5 &8 &7 &4 &1 &3 \\
6 &8 &2 &7 &5 &1 &7 &8 &8 \\
8 &6 &6 &7 &6 &7 &1 &7 &8 \\
1 &7 &5 &5 &7 &1 &2 &3 &4 \\
4 &7 &4 &7 &5 &3 &3 &7 &9 \\
1 &9 &8 &2 &3 &7 &7 &8 &2 \\
1 &5 &6 &6 &1 &2 &9 &8 &7 \\
6 &7 &9 &8 &7 &9 &5 &2 &2 \\
8 &4 &1 &3 &1 &4 &7 &2 &9 \\
2 &9 &3 &8 &9 &4 &4 &2 &4 \\
8 &5 &2 &7 &3 &9 &6 &2 &5 \\
4 &8 &5 &3 &9 &5 &8 &2 &3 \\
3 &8 &7 &3 &4 &1 &9 &4 &1 \\
9 &9 &7 &3 &7 &6 &2 &8 &7 \\
7 &9 &2 &4 &4 &8 &7 &2 &1 \\
5 &5 &8 &4 &9 &8 &9 &9 &6 \\
7 &4 &5 &8 &8 &2 &2 &6 &2 \\
4 &7 &3 &4 &3 &2 &7 &1 &3 \\
2 &4 &9 &6 &5 &3 &8 &4 &8 \\
7 &7 &7 &1 &1 &3 &9 &1 &8 \\
8 &1 &1 &1 &7 &5 &8 &7 &4 \\
8 &7 &8 &5 &2 &5 &1 &6 &3 \\
3 &2 &8 &4 &6 &3 &6 &8 &7 \\
1 &7 &9 &7 &6 &5 &6 &1 &6 \\
1 &1 &7 &4 &4 &4 &2 &7 &9 \\
6 &6 &6 &6 &2 &8 &5 &9 &9 \\
5 &6 &7 &6 &3 &3 &4 &5 &3 \\
6 &3 &5 &8 &3 &5 &1 &9 &6 \\
9 &2 &5 &4 &7 &5 &5 &1 &8 \\
7 &8 &3 &8 &7 &8 &8 &3 &8 \\
9 &2 &1 &2 &2 &8 &8 &8 &3 \\
4 &9 &1 &7 &1 &5 &4 &5 &2 \\
9 &4 &6 &9 &3 &7 &8 &2 &4 \\
8 &5 &7 &1 &8 &8 &5 &4 &3 \\
3 &4 &4 &8 &7 &5 &7 &8 &3 \\
7 &5 &2 &5 &1 &1 &8 &9 &9 \\
6 &6 &9 &2 &9 &4 &2 &3 &3 \\
3 &1 &6 &2 &1 &3 &1 &9 &3 \\
4 &6 &4 &2 &8 &8 &6 &1 &2 \\
9 &7 &1 &9 &4 &3 &7 &6 &2 \\
4 &2 &3 &2 &5 &5 &1 &3 &7 \\
6 &5 &4 &3 &4 &4 &8 &5 &5 \\
5 &1 &9 &9 &3 &5 &9 &8 &5 \\
7 &4 &6 &2 &4 &1 &6 &8 &5 \\
3 &3 &4 &1 &9 &3 &5 &2 &6 \\
7 &3 &2 &1 &7 &4 &4 &8 &2 \\
1 &6 &3 &9 &2 &4 &8 &1 &7 \\
3 &2 &3 &7 &3 &4 &5 &9 &2 \\
5 &7 &2 &3 &7 &7 &6 &4 &8 \\
4 &9 &6 &5 &3 &1 &9 &6 &8 \\
5 &5 &5 &1 &5 &2 &4 &1 &5 \\
5 &5 &3 &9 &1 &6 &2 &5 &1 \\
5 &2 &8 &3 &4 &2 &1 &7 &2 \\
7 &6 &8 &5 &3 &4 &6 &4 &6 \\
9 &6 &9 &5 &1 &3 &5 &8 &4 \\
3 &7 &3 &9 &6 &1 &3 &2 &8 \\
2 &2 &4 &1 &3 &8 &7 &6 &4 \\
8 &7 &4 &6 &8 &4 &4 &3 &8 \\
7 &2 &4 &6 &1 &9 &5 &7 &3 \\
4 &5 &4 &8 &6 &2 &1 &2 &1 \\
7 &1 &3 &5 &4 &5 &3 &1 &2 \\
9 &7 &8 &1 &6 &6 &8 &4 &5 \\
7 &6 &1 &9 &5 &7 &3 &8 &1 \\
6 &2 &1 &5 &7 &3 &9 &5 &6 \\
5 &7 &4 &5 &4 &6 &9 &2 &7 \\
2 &8 &6 &4 &1 &7 &7 &5 &6 \\
3 &6 &1 &4 &4 &2 &8 &9 &8 \\
7 &3 &9 &9 &2 &9 &7 &5 &8 \\
5 &8 &5 &5 &2 &3 &6 &9 &2 \\
3 &5 &4 &9 &2 &7 &9 &6 &9 \\
8 &3 &4 &7 &1 &2 &2 &9 &4 \\
9 &2 &7 &7 &1 &1 &3 &3 &5 \\
6 &5 &8 &9 &3 &3 &5 &3 &8 \\
3 &6 &5 &5 &6 &6 &7 &1 &9 \\
3 &1 &5 &6 &8 &8 &3 &8 &4 \\
6 &9 &7 &9 &9 &8 &1 &1 &5 \\
5 &2 &6 &5 &9 &4 &3 &8 &9 \\
5 &3 &6 &4 &5 &5 &2 &4 &2 \\
6 &4 &6 &1 &8 &3 &7 &7 &7 \\
5 &9 &6 &7 &7 &9 &7 &1 &4 \\
2 &7 &3 &3 &4 &8 &5 &8 &6 \\
2 &9 &5 &3 &6 &3 &9 &3 &5 \\
2 &4 &5 &9 &4 &6 &4 &9 &3 \\
4 &8 &3 &6 &2 &9 &4 &8 &1 \\
8 &9 &4 &4 &7 &1 &6 &5 &9 \\
9 &9 &3 &9 &5 &9 &6 &4 &3 \\
5 &1 &1 &6 &6 &1 &7 &9 &1 \\
3 &8 &8 &6 &7 &4 &1 &2 &5 \\
4 &5 &5 &7 &2 &4 &7 &3 &6 \\
3 &4 &6 &5 &5 &8 &4 &3 &6 \\
7 &8 &7 &2 &3 &9 &3 &6 &7 \\
2 &1 &3 &7 &7 &7 &2 &6 &3 \\
9 &1 &4 &3 &5 &7 &4 &9 &2 \\
5 &6 &9 &1 &7 &1 &1 &6 &7 \\
6 &3 &7 &6 &8 &7 &2 &2 &1 \\
6 &8 &9 &5 &4 &2 &4 &6 &9 \\
7 &4 &8 &1 &9 &9 &1 &3 &9 \\
6 &3 &3 &7 &9 &6 &3 &4 &7 \\
8 &8 &3 &1 &5 &4 &9 &6 &6 \\
2 &3 &8 &5 &5 &7 &9 &7 &4 \\
1 &6 &4 &4 &5 &9 &7 &3 &5 \\
3 &1 &2 &8 &3 &6 &4 &7 &8 \\
6 &4 &9 &4 &2 &6 &9 &1 &4 \\
2 &5 &3 &4 &8 &9 &8 &7 &2 \\
8 &1 &5 &5 &3 &2 &5 &5 &7 \\
9 &5 &8 &6 &5 &5 &7 &5 &9 \\
4 &4 &2 &4 &9 &3 &4 &6 &5 \\
2 &5 &6 &2 &9 &5 &5 &6 &1 \\
9 &7 &6 &8 &8 &1 &1 &1 &9 \\
8 &8 &7 &8 &6 &5 &2 &5 &5 \\
1 &8 &1 &8 &8 &9 &9 &9 &4 \\
7 &6 &2 &3 &8 &5 &9 &5 &7 \\
5 &4 &2 &7 &6 &2 &8 &3 &7 \\
3 &2 &9 &8 &1 &8 &2 &4 &9 \\
4 &4 &7 &2 &7 &4 &8 &9 &1 \\
2 &7 &1 &7 &3 &6 &1 &3 &1 \\
7 &9 &7 &6 &2 &5 &6 &3 &4 \\
4 &3 &2 &9 &4 &1 &2 &1 &6 \\
2 &5 &9 &8 &4 &7 &6 &3 &7 \\
9 &3 &5 &7 &4 &9 &9 &8 &9 \\
6 &7 &5 &4 &5 &8 &8 &6 &7 \\
4 &1 &1 &8 &5 &4 &5 &4 &5 \\
1 &6 &8 &7 &4 &1 &5 &2 &3 \\
4 &8 &6 &1 &4 &6 &5 &3 &4 \\
1 &3 &3 &3 &8 &3 &6 &6 &9
\end{matrix}

Comment: Just saw this problem. Interesting one. Thanks for this. It shows Q = 9 will work. How do we prove mathematically without linear programming that Q = 9 would suffice? It is easy to prove $5 \lt Q \le 13$ but cannot think how to go from there.